# New to javascript and trying to use setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm quite new to javascript and I want a the crickit.motor1.run(60) to get set to 0 after 2 seconds but it isn't working and I'm kinda out of options for what to do next.
This is my code

```js
forever(function() {
  if (crickit.touch1.touchRead() > 400) {
    light.setPixelColor(0, 0x00ffff)
    crickit.motor1.run(60);
  }

  pause(100)
})

function motorOff() {
  crickit.motor1.run(0);
}

forever(function() {
  if (crickit.motor1.run() = 60)
    setTimeout(motorOff() {

    }, 2000);
})
```

Comment: don't call `motorOff` function, just pass the name of the function to `setTimeout` --> `setTimeout(motorOff, 2000);`

Comment: `crickit.motor1.run() = 60` should be using `==` or `===` for comparison. Singular `=` is for assignment

Answer (score 0):

These will work:

`setTimeout( motorOff, 2000);`

`setTimeout( 'motorOff()', 2000);`

`setTimeout( function() { motorOff() }, 2000);`

Comment: It still saying that I made a mistake somewhere in this part: forever(function () {
    if (crickit.motor1.run() == 60)
        setTimeout(function () { motorOff() }, 2000);
})
and I have no idea what that would be

Comment: @Snain and there is no error message ?

Comment: There is supposed to be `if () {line1 line2}` if there is no `{}`, JS adds only the first line to `if`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it like this:
`setTimeout(motorOff, 2000);`

If you have a function that uses parameters, lets say motorOff(param) would accept 1 paramter, you have to use it like this:
`setTimeout(motorOff, 2000, param);`